# UICollection view didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working well

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have made simple collectionview in uiviewcontroller but didSelectItemAtIndexPath not always reacts to touch of cells. DataSource and Delegates are connected on storyboard. For example if i touch all my cells it doesnt return all of them, 2 or 3 of cells even are not clickable .

Below is my code

```
//TestCollectionView.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface TestCollectionView : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollection;

    @end
```

TestCollectionView.m

```
#import "TestCollectionView.h"
#import "TestCell.h"

@interface TestCollectionView ()

@end

@implementation TestCollectionView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      TestCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"testCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"slected index is %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

}


@end
```

Comment: A small clarification, you should use `indexPath.item` with collection views; `indexPath.row` is for table views, but that won't cause your problem.  Is your collection view perhaps occluded by some other UI element?  What constraints have you set on it?  Is it always cells in the same location that cannot be selected?

Comment: Turn on clipToBounds property as true for your collection view. I think your cells are out of bound

Comment: i just put collectionview from storybard and put it on viewcontroller and cliptobound is set on true, my cells are correctly located

Comment: everytime when i run application the different cell becomes untouchable, i even put debugger on didSelectItemAtIndexPath no reaction at all for unclickable cells

Comment: by the way iam using xcode 9.4

Comment: Did you set any constraints when you added the collection view?  if not then do so; constrain it to the four edges of your scene

Comment: it didnt help @Paulw11

Comment: can you please add the code for TestCell?

Comment: Register your cell or check cell identifier.

Comment: thanks i fixed my bug it seems like something was wrong with ios simulator when i deleted app from simulator and reinstalled it everything worked fine

Comment: Did you add delegate and dataSource by your design ?